# Call adapter.notifyItemChanged(position); working so weird

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a list that I get from firebase, this list is about posts and what I need is when user like it or unlike it, the list updated through adapter. as I used recyclerview and adapter to show my data after receiving it from firebase. Actually, everything works so fine with me but just this issue when user like or unlike the post it goes crazy. I tried to make a toast to make sure that I'm working with the same position as I expected and it proved me right.

the photo of the post appears and disappears by clicking like button like the vides shows and it does not updating the data in a proper way like it mess with the number of likes

You can find my code below with a video to illustrate the problem I am facing.

I hope somebody can help me out.

[image: This how I mean by working so weird]

```
private void read_posts() {


    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            //post_models.clear();

                Post_Model post_model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post_Model.class);


                post_models.add(post_model);


            post_adapter = new Post_Adapter(post_models, getContext());
            recyclerviewNewsfeed.setAdapter(post_adapter);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);




        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


            Post_Model post_model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post_Model.class);



            for (int i=0;i<post_models.size();i++){

                if(post_models.get(i).getId().equals(post_model.getId())){





                    post_models.set(i,post_model);

                    post_adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);


                    break;


                }



            }






        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });







}
```

It's my post adapter

```
public class Post_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Post_Adapter.Viewholder> {



private Context context;

private List<Post_Model> post_models;

FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

List<Like_Model> like_modelList, likeblue_modelList;


View_Photos_Adapter view_Photos_adapter;

boolean userlikeit;

public static int positionn=-1;

public Post_Adapter(List<Post_Model> post_models, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.post_models = post_models;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);


    return new Viewholder(view);

}


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Viewholder holder, final int position) {


    final Post_Model post_model = post_models.get(position);


    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();



    DatabaseReference referencee = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(post_model.getId());

    referencee.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            //Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, post_id+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                Post_Model post_modell = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post_Model.class);



                    // Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, post_id+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    if (post_modell.getLikeModels() != null) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < post_modell.getLikeModels().size(); i++) {

                            if (post_modell.getLikeModels().get(i).getUserid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {

                                userlikeit = true;

                                break;

                            } else {

                                userlikeit = false;

                            }

                        }


                    } else {

                        userlikeit = false;

                    }

                    //snapshot.getRef().removeValue();






            // Toast.makeText(context, userlikeit+"58", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, comment_models.size()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if (userlikeit) {

                holder.likebluebtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.likebtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {

                holder.likebtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.likebluebtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    if (post_model.getUserid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {

        holder.editbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.deletebtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {

        holder.editbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.deletebtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }





    holder.editbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            holder.postTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.postEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.postEditText.setText(post_model.getPost());

            holder.editbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.savebtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    });


    holder.savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Post_Model post_modell = new Post_Model(post_model.getId(), post_model.getUserid()
                    ,  holder.postEditText.getText().toString(), post_model.getTime()
                    , post_model.getCommentModels(), post_model.getPostphotos(), post_model.getLikeModels());

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
                    .child(post_model.getId())
                    .setValue(post_modell);

            holder.postTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.postEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.editbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.savebtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            Toast.makeText(context, "Post has been edited successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsfeedActivity.class);

            context.startActivity(intent);

            ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);


            ((Activity) context).finish();

        }
    });


    holder.deletebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Delete Post")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this post?")

                    // Specifying a listener allows you to take an action before dismissing the dialog.
                    // The dialog is automatically dismissed when a dialog button is clicked.
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            final DatabaseReference referencee = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
                                    .child(post_model.getId());

                            referencee.removeValue();


                            Toast.makeText(context, "Post deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsfeedActivity.class);

                            context.startActivity(intent);

                            ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);

                            ((Activity) context).finish();

                        }
                    })

                    // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();


        }

    });


    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    like_modelList = new ArrayList<>();

    likeblue_modelList = new ArrayList<>();


    //Toast.makeText(context, read_likes(post_model.getId())+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                // Toast.makeText(Create_Coworking_SpaceActivity.this, "111111111", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                if (user.getId().equals(post_model.getUserid())) {

                    if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")) {

                        holder.userImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_imgprofile);

                    } else {

                        Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(user.getImageURL()).into( holder.userImage);

                    }

                    holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());

                }


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    if (post_model.getPostphotos() == null) {

        holder.postPhotosRC.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else {

        holder.postPhotosRC.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.postPhotosRC.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        view_Photos_adapter = new View_Photos_Adapter(post_model.getPostphotos(), context);

        holder.postPhotosRC.setAdapter(view_Photos_adapter);
    }


    holder.postTextView.setText(post_model.getPost());

    holder.posttimeTextView.setText(post_model.getTime());


    holder.commentbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CommentActivity.class);


            intent.putExtra("post_id", post_model.getId());


            context.startActivity(intent);

            ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);


        }
    });

    if (post_model.getCommentModels() != null) {

        holder.numofcommentsEditText.setText(post_model.getCommentModels().size() + "");

        holder.numofcommentsTextView.setText(post_model.getCommentModels().size() + "");
    }


    final int[] li = {0};

    holder.likebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            like(post_model.getId());

           // Post_Adapter.this.notifyItemChanged(position);

            positionn=position;


        }
    });


    holder.likebluebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Toast.makeText(context, userlikeit+"5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            unlike(post_model.getId());

           // Post_Adapter.this.notifyItemChanged(position);

            positionn=position;

        }
    });

    if (post_model.getLikeModels() != null) {

        holder.numoflikesEditText.setText(post_model.getLikeModels().size() + "");

        holder.numoflikesTextView.setText(post_model.getLikeModels().size() + "");
    }


    holder.likesTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LikeActivity.class);


            intent.putExtra("post_id", post_model.getId());


            context.startActivity(intent);

            ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);


        }
    });



    holder.commentsTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CommentActivity.class);


            intent.putExtra("post_id", post_model.getId());


            context.startActivity(intent);

            ((Activity) 
     context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, 
         R.anim.slide_in_left);


        }
    });



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return post_models == null ? 0 : post_models.size();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean of post getting crazy?

Comment: the photo of the post appears and disappears by clicking like button like the gif show and it does not updating the data in a proper way like it mess with the number of likes

Comment: I think problem is with your Post_Adapter, post your Post_Adapter too

Comment: Okay, it's done

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 550 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.